# Android memory leaks heap gc_concurrent

Tags: java, android, performance, memory, memory-leaks

Can somebody tell me why am I having these memory leaks?
It happens when splash screen needs to finish itself (basically call a new activity)
And again it happens when I'm opening a new page (new activity) on a button click in the menu.

Log cat memory leaks :

Splash screen to main menu :

```
12-07 19:35:58.037: D/dalvikvm(2167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 499K, 21% free 4138K/5228K, paused 8ms+8ms, total 397ms
12-07 19:35:58.045: D/dalvikvm(2167): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 170ms
12-07 19:35:58.116: I/dalvikvm-heap(2167): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.208MB for 1106044-byte allocation
12-07 19:35:58.365: D/dalvikvm(2167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 18% free 5215K/6312K, paused 8ms+33ms, total 246ms
```

Main menu to a new page :

```
12-07 19:38:30.974: D/dalvikvm(2167): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 17% free 5272K/6304K, paused 119ms, total 151ms
12-07 19:38:31.034: I/dalvikvm-heap(2167): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.316MB for 1106044-byte allocation
12-07 19:38:31.376: D/dalvikvm(2167): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1129K, 30% free 5224K/7388K, paused 89ms+5ms, total 332ms
```

Here is my main :

```
package com.example.prva;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer MPlayer; //da MPlayer mozemo koristiti bilo gdje
    protected boolean splashactive = true;
    protected int splashtime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);        

        MPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splash); //dodavanje zvuka MPlayeru
        MPlayer.start();        //play

        Thread tajmer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{        
                    while(splashactive && splashtime<3000)
                        {
                            sleep(50);
                            splashtime=splashtime+50;
                        }
                    }
                 catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
                finally{
                    finish();                   
                    MPlayer.release();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Meni_Splash.class));                
                }       
            }           
        };
        tajmer.start(); 
    }       

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            splashactive = false;           

        }       
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        MPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        MPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        MPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Meni_Splash :

```
package com.example.prva;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Meni_Splash extends Activity{  


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        Button btnv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonv);
        btnv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Meni_Splash.this, button.class));              
            }
        });         
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where is the problem?
Please don't tell me to increase the heap size.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Its normal man...nothing bad about it... Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any leak here unless you hold a reference to one of these activity somewhere else.
For example `MPlayer` is not private or protected so if you hold a reference to it in another instance you might have a leak.

It is normal to have garbage collection when the `MediaPlayer` is involved. It can take a lot of memory

Your `MainActivity` stays in memory even if a new Activity is started. If you don't want that call `finish();` after `startActivity();`

Comment: Yeah I already have finish(); in the finally{} if that's what you meant. If you could explain in a little bit more detail your statement : "For example MPlayer is not private or protected so if hold a reference to it in another instance you might have a leak." I would be very grateful! I understand that MPlayer is not protected nor private, but why would it need to be? What do you mean by "another instance". Sorry, I'm new to all this.

Comment: Since it's not private, nothing will prevent another Activity from doing Mplayer myPlayer = mainActivity.MPlayer;   In that case, the mainActivity and all its variable could not be GC'd until myPlayer is GC's in the other activity. That is exactly what a memory leak is, and the reason why you are generally encouraged to use private variables.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it, thanks. But how can another Activity use the MPlayer on itself, without my coding thus opening a leak?

Comment: I don't know, it's just that having not seen the rest of your code I said that it could be a source of memory leak. If you're not referencing MPlayer somewhere else then you're fine and you don't have any memory leak. It looks just like normal GC activity when the MediaPlayer is in use

Comment: No I'm not using it anywhere else, its a sound for the splash screen only. MPlayer is protected now just to be sure. :)

Comment: Although when I see that the GC concurrent paused again for 300ms twice, I start to wonder...